# Using subprocess.run to run Snakemake

Tags: python, subprocess, snakemake

I am trying to run `sankemake` within python script using cluster configuration where `myoutput/output.txt` one of my output results:

```
cluster = """ "qsub -A {cluster.account}  -l walltime={cluster.time} -q {cluster.queue} -l nodes=1:ppn={cluster.nCPUs} -l mem={cluster.memory}" """  

subprocess.run(['snakemake',  '-p', "myoutput/output.txt", '-j 200', '--cluster-config', cluster_config, '--cluster', cluster])
```

I have this error:

```
/bin/sh: qsub -A proj_A  -l walltime=72:00:00 -q analysis -l nodes=1:ppn=20,mem=30G: command not found
```

I see that snakemake submitting to `/bin/sh` where `qsub` actually in `/usr/bin/qsub`.

Any Idea how to solve it or is there a better implementation?

Thanks

Comment: You need to split all your arguments before passing them to `subprocess.run()'. `subprocess` will do all the shell escaping for you.

Comment: you mean the `cluster` part?

Comment: Yes, also `-j 200` should be two elements of the list passed. Write down the whole command you'd use in shell, then split it on whitespace and pass it as such to `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: I will try it, but in snakemake documentation this is how to use cluster `--cluster "qsub -pe threaded {threads}"` it needs to be passed in one string as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought that I need to pass the cluster in double quotes to the `--cluster` flag as suggested by documentation so I used.

```
cluster = """ "qsub -A {cluster.account}  -l walltime={cluster.time} -q {cluster.queue} -l nodes=1:ppn={cluster.nCPUs} -l mem={cluster.memory}" """
```

but actually that what lead to the error, when I used in this way:

```
cluster = "qsub -A {cluster.account}  -l walltime={cluster.time} -q {cluster.queue} -l nodes=1:ppn={cluster.nCPUs} -l mem={cluster.memory}"
```

It run as it should be.